# Eclipse - How to import java projects in a Working Set

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Eclipse: How to import maven projects in a Working Set and see them as a Java projects not as a folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse normally uses the standards defined to adapt the project to the appropriate view. If the project does not use the directory structure properly you could manually define as follows

- **Right-click (panel projects) -> Import -> maven -> existing maven
  project**
- **Select root directory (should recognize the pom file)**
- **Right-click the imported project -> write "Project facets" -> select
  one or more facets of the project**

---

*Recommendation: If Eclipse does not automatically recognized, you should review the structure of your project to see what's out of place.*